# Why can I use named pipes to connect to SQL Server even if it's been disabled?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, connectivity, protocol

Why can I still use named pipes to connect to SQL Server even if it's been disabled? I'm on SQL Server 2016 doing the testing. I have recorded my operation in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lvkbwsspZc Hope someone can point me the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the SQL Server error log for the named pipes provider messages.  With named pipes enabled, you should see messages like those below and be able to connect both locally and remotely over named pipes:

> Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on (named pipe)
>
> Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on (named pipe)

With named pipes disabled, you should see only local connection provider message(s).  You'll still be able to connect locally via named pipes (over shared memory) but not remotely via named pipes.

Comment: Thanks Dan, It seems that you are correct. I only see local connection information in my error log. But I have two:`Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ].
Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\sql\query ].` Is this behavior documented in books online? I can't find them anywhere. How do you know it?

Comment: @OgrishMan, I don't know if/where this is documented but shared memory is a local named pipe implementation.  I learned this recently from the Microsoft contact Erland mentioned in an MSDN forum answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/263f8794-8aee-4a3a-b59e-4e58c2323c51/sql-server-2016-named-pipes-still-accepts-a-connection-even-when-disabled-in-configuration-manager